# What is going on with this loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a row of squares, the number of which is dictated by the user input.
I expected the x coordinate of each square to be multiplied by the number of times the loop runs by the width of each square.
So far it seems to either only be drawing one square, or I am feeding the draw function the same coordinates each loop.
Can anyone spot my error?

```
def main():
    seed()  # Initialize random number generator

    top_left_x = 100
    top_left_y = 100
    width = 60
    height = 60
    y_num = 0
    # num_rows = int(input('Number of rows: '))  # commented out for now
    num_columns = int(input('Number of columns: '))



    for i in range (num_columns):
        window = GraphWin('Lab 3B', 800, 800)
        new_x = i * width + top_left_x
        new_y = top_left_y
        top_left_point = Point(new_x, new_y)
        bottom_right_point = Point(new_x + width, new_y + height)
        enclosing_rectangle = Rectangle(top_left_point, bottom_right_point)
        enclosing_rectangle.setFill(random_color())
        enclosing_rectangle.draw(window)

    for i in range(10):
        c_point = window.getMouse()
        x_c_point = c_point.getX()
        y_c_point = c_point.getY()
        print('x =', x_c_point, 'y =', y_c_point)

    window.getMouse()
    window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range (num_columns):
    window = GraphWin('Lab 3B', 800, 800)
    new_x = i * width + top_left_x
```

This recreates the window every time round the loop. Swap the first two lines like this:

```
window = GraphWin('Lab 3B', 800, 800)
for i in range (num_columns):
    new_x = i * width + top_left_x
```

However, the next problem is that you also only ever have one rectangle, so you need to save each rectangle you create, so this should work:

```
window = GraphWin('Lab 3B', 800, 800)
rects = [] # Stores rectangles
for i in range (num_columns):
    new_x = i * width + top_left_x
    new_y = top_left_y
    top_left_point = Point(new_x, new_y)
    bottom_right_point = Point(new_x + width, new_y + height)
    enclosing_rectangle = Rectangle(top_left_point, bottom_right_point)
    enclosing_rectangle.setFill(random_color())
    enclosing_rectangle.draw(window)
    rects.append(enclosing_rectangle) # Keep this rectangle
```

Comment: Okay yeah that makes sense, thank you! It is still drawing only one square though

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer; you need to keep all the `Rectangle` objects around for the duration of the program